# using kind to pull images from a local registry

Tags: kubernetes, registry, kind

I'm using Kind to deploy a docker image from a local repository.  I followed the article on https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-run-locally-built-docker-images-in-kubernetes-b28fbc32cc1d and setup the local repository.  Once I try to deploy the k8s deployment I see the following error on the pod

```
  Normal   Scheduled  9s    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/chatt-deployment-675c8dd456-m25mm to kind-control-plane
  Normal   Pulling    8s    kubelet            Pulling image "localhost:5000/chatt:latest"
  Warning  Failed     8s    kubelet            Failed to pull image "localhost:5000/chatt:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "localhost:5000/chatt:latest": failed to resolve reference "localhost:5000/chatt:latest": failed to do request: Head "http://kind-registry:5000/v2/chatt/manifests/latest?ns=localhost%3A5000": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp [::1]:3128: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Failed     8s    kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    7s    kubelet            Back-off pulling image "localhost:5000/chatt:latest"
  Warning  Failed     7s    kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Do you know how I can fix this.

Comment: (a) that's [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for a programming website (b) [the fine manual compels you](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/local-registry/) or its alternative, [loading the image from a tar](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/#loading-an-image-into-your-cluster)